# Responsive image code not grabbing appropriate resolution image

Tags: html, css

Trying to use responsive sizing for my hero image. Everything looks how it is supposed to and is arranged correctly, but I noticed that no matter what width the browser is, it always grabs the same (lowest quality) image. I'm checking this by resizing the screen, right clicking, and selecting 'open image in new tab', then checking the resolution there.

Screen resolution is 1366x768
Browser is Brave (Chromium)
Image resolutions are listed in the file names

I'm hoping you might be able to spot where the issue is.

```
<head>
  <meta charset='UTF-8' />
  <title>Title</title>
  <link rel='stylesheet' href='styles.css' />
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
  <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0' />
</head>

<body>
  <div class='page'>
    <div class='menu'>
    </div>
    <div class='section hero-image'>
        <div class='photo'>
          <picture>
            <source media='(min-width: 601px)' srcset='images/Dam-Hero-image 1959x1306.jpg'/>
            <source media='(max-width: 600px)' srcset='images/Dam-Hero-image 800x1100.jpg'/>
            <img src='images/Dam-Hero-image 980x653.jpg'/>
          </picture>
        </div>
      </div>
```

```
/* Page styles */
.page {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

/* Hero styles */
.hero-image {
    height: auto;
    justify-content: inherit;
    align-items: inherit;
}

.photo img {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}
```

```
/* Mobile Styles */
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
    .hero-message {
        width: 100%;
    }
}

/* Tablet Styles */
@media only screen and (min-width: 601px) and (max-width: 960px) {

}

/* Desktop Styles */
@media only screen and (min-width: 961px) {
    .page {
        width: 960px;
    }
}

It should change the image being used when the browser crosses the given pixel threshold, but I suppose its something else like the images are too big or the browser needs to be refreshed each time (although I've tried this already). Thanks for your help!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possibly due to your filenames?
`srcset='images/Dam-Hero-image 1959x1306.jpg'`

I personally hate using spaces in filenames as it always causes issues. Try changing it to an _

Also your `<img src='images/Dam-Hero-image 980x653.jpg'/>` is tiny. This is the goto for browsers that dont support srcset. So its possible your code is broken with the srcset filenames with the spaces so its defaulting to the img (which is tiny)

Comment: Thank you, it was definitely the filenames.

Answer (score 0):

```
.photo img {
width: 100%;
display: block;
```

maybe your issue is with `.photo img {`.... I think you want `.photo, img {`

EDIT:

I just noticed that you have `@media only screen`.
I think that it should be, simply,  `@media screen`.